# What's the point of java.io.BufferedWriter.min(int a, int b)?

Tags: java, java-io, bufferedwriter

In `java.io.BufferedWriter` there is a method:

```
/**
 * Our own little min method, to avoid loading java.lang.Math if we've run
 * out of file descriptors and we're trying to print a stack trace.
 */
private int min(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) return a;
    return b;
}
```

What's the point of this method? Extra file descriptor required to load `java.lang.Math`?

If I compile and run empty program with `-verbose:class`

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

I will get in logs:

```
[Loaded java.lang.Math from /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_65/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

Comment: Ha! Probabaly written in 1995.

Comment: I think the comment is descriptive enough. What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your JVM fails very early, Math might not yet be loaded.  Your JVM does an awful lot of works and runs a lot of code before `main` is called. This means a lot can go wrong before you get to this point.

For example, this simple program

```
public class HowManyStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Hello world");
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

Creates around 10,000 objects.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/common-misconception-how-many-objects.html

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying this:

If you had run out of file descriptors while trying to print a stack trace, and you invoked `Math.min(a, b)`, and Math had not yet been loaded by the classloader (unlikely but could happen, eg in startup), then you wouldn't be able to even generate the stack trace. So they've added `min` directly to the `BufferedWriter` class to avoid this.